# Import data from txt file or excel to Oracle vbscript in VB Script

Tags: excel, vba

I have a script that runs and connects to Oracle DB to validate the data availability for the values which are received from sheet1 .Now i wanted to modify the script to take the values from text file present in particular directory instead of using same Excel and write the values to another text file in same path

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Currently SQL query receiving values from Excel sheet1 instead of that i want to pass those values from separate text file present in particular directory

Comment: And what prevents you to do so?

Comment: I am new to VB. I am figuring out the code to do the same .Seeking help here

Comment: So your question is not about Oracle? Your title suggests so. There are plenty of Question (and answers) on SO about how to read and write text files using VBA.

Comment: search for `filesystemobject` and you'll find plenty of examples